# SpringBootのRequestParamにてスペース文字を受け取りたい

Tags: java, spring-boot

RequestParamの`List<String>`にて、スペース文字(%20)を受け取りたいのですが、空しか取れません。

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/example")
public String param(@RequestParam(name = "param", required = false) List<String> param) {
    if (param == null) {
        param = Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return param.toString();
}
```

カンマ区切りで下記を実行すると、"AAA","","BBB"となってしまいます。
http://localhost:8080/api/example?param=AAA,%20,BBB
[image: カンマ区切り]

下記のようにパラメータ自体を分けてあげれば、正常に動作するのは確認できました。
http://localhost:8080/api/example?param=AAA&param=%20&param=BBB
[image: パラメータ区切り]

カンマ区切りでもスペース文字を正常に受け取る方法があればご教授ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Provide mechanism to control trimming in StringToArrayConverter and StringToCollectionConverter · Issue #23850 · spring-projects/spring-framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23850)

と同源の事象かと思います。現状フレームワーク組み込みの機能でコントロールすることはできないので自前で実装する必要がありそうです。

---

Controller引数の型変換は`WebDataBinder`でカスタマイズできます。

- [Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion) - 1.3.3. Handler Methods
- [1.3.5. DataBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder)

配列への変換であればユーティリティクラス[`StringArrayPropertyEditor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/StringArrayPropertyEditor.java#L88-L89)が提供されていたのでこれを用いて実装してみました([コード全体](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/blob/master/so65419/src/main/java/com/example/demo/MyController.java)):

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String[].class, new StringArrayPropertyEditor(",", false, false));
}

@GetMapping(path = "/api/example")
public String param(@RequestParam(name = "param", required = false) final String[] paramArray) {
    final List<String> param;
    if (paramArray == null) {
        param = Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
        param = Arrays.asList(paramArray);
    }
    return param.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

動作検証はしていませんが、おそらく、[この辺](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToArrayConverter.java#L72)で`String.trim()`してるからだと思います。

なので、`List<String>`ではなく、`String`で受け取って、Controllerで`List<String>`に変換するのが1つの対応方法ですかね。

※最終的に`return param.toString();`するなら、`List<String>`に変換しなくてもいいかもしれませんが...

Comment: 今回のコードで用いられているのは[`StringToCollectionConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToCollectionConverter.java#L80)の方ですね。